# Why is mist abbreviated BR on METARs and TAFs?

Tags: weather, metar

The abbreviation for a condition of mist is `BR` on METAR and TAF reports. How did mist end up getting abbreviated as BR?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[According to a CFI's lesson plan on the internet](http://www.cfidarren.com/r-metarmystery.htm), it comes from the French word for mist, **[*brume*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brume)**.

Comment: I believe Smoke (`FU`) is also from the French (fumée)

Comment: as well as Hail (`GR`)  from French *grêle*.

Comment: The word "brouillard" would also fit and is more common, as far as I know. It's used on traffic signs in France.

Comment: Looked up the difference: brouillard is used when visibility is less than 1 km, brume is for visibility between 1 and 5 km.

Comment: "brume" is more used for mist while "brouillard" would be more often translated as fog (which would have reduced visibility).

Comment: A useful mnemonic for BR is "baby rain".