# Why does GR mean hail in a METAR?

Tags: weather, metar

Wouldn't you think they'd choose HL instead?

That might confuse pilots who frequently see SS (Sandstorms),
 DS (Dust Storms) and VA (Volcanic Ash).

Comment: Related: [Why is mist abbreviated BR on METARs and TAFs?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/21250/1696)

Comment: "Granite Rain".  No, not really, but it's a reasonable mnemonic.

Comment: And smoke is FU—from Fumée

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The French word for hail is *grêle* which is abbreviated GR.  METAR is an international standard so you will see some non-English words included in the METAR.

Comment: Hail in spanish is Granizo, so probably from latin :D